# How can I tell what AD paths an AD user will be able to query over LDAP?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

How can I tell what AD paths a user will be able to query over LDAP? Eg. when I connect to our mock AD controller server as a test user via Microsoft [ADExplorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/adexplorer), I notice I can look at (what appears to be) the entire AD structure and have the ability to edit any other object in any path.

Is there somewhere in this test user's attributes where I can see where this access is specified? Somewhere in the user's properties in the AD Admin Center UI? Basically, I want to limit it so that they can only query their own base (or a few select) [OU](http://www.selfadsi.org/ldap-path.htm)s/directories when making LDAP queries or connecting over ADExplorer.

When I connect to AD controller via ADExplorer, I can look at everything including paths that the connecting user is not a Member of (they are only a member of `myorg.local/Users`) or included in a child path of.

The basic AD structure looks like...

```
myorg.local (DC,DC)
    ...
    testing (OU)
        groups (OU)
        ...
        users (OU)
            testuser (CN)
    ...
    Users (CN)
other1.local (DC,DC)
    ...
other2.local (DC,DC)
    ...
```

...yet testuser can read everything

Also, is there a way to restrict them from connecting over ADEXplorer and similar apps?

Answer (score 0):

These are some answers I've seen around...

> Default is read access to the entire domain. You cannot deny read to
> the OU the user is in, the OUs for any other resources the user uses
> (say, computers in a separate OU), or any of their parent containers.
>
> Blocking AD traffic is notoriously tricky- you’re better off
> preventing unauthorized users from running the rogue apps on
> domain-joined devices in the first place, and falling back on the
> permissions to be sure only authorized admins/power users can edit AD
> objects- usually by delegation.
>
> **Here are steps on removing their ability to read sensitive OU’s**.
>
> https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29558.active-directory-controlling-object-visibility-list-object-mode.aspx
>
> I recommend setting up a test domain to play around with this before
> implementing in prod as it can have serious consequences if done
> wrong.

> Active Directory is just that - a directory. LDAP... the D is for
> Dieectory. It was designed this way, many services and components in
> AD, Windows, or other solutions rely on this.
>
> Several option there!
>
> Tbh the easiest might be to maintain another source of project-name to
> project-access-granting-group-name map, or to use abbreviations for
> the project group that would be meaningless to anyone outside the
> group.
>
> Another option would be to use specific attributes on these groups to
> track their real name (similar to first option above. Attributes not
> used by various systems are much easier to lock down than entire
> accounts/groups/etc, but might entail you extending the schema.
>
> Maintaining a map of your groups, to organization specific things like
> projects provides a useful set of data, so the first option (another
> source to map names) is what I would tend to go with, but I haven’t
> been in an environment with that constraint, so someone who has might
> have more insight into alternatives

Will refine this answer more when get back to this problem and do more work on it